# Solving these boolean expressions

Tags: logic

I'd like someone to check if this is correct, because I'm not quite sure if I get this. I think I do, but I got too many Trues.

1. (not(F and F)) or F == T
2. (not(F and F)) or T == T
3. (not(F and T)) or F == T
4. (not(F and T)) or T == T
5. (not(T and F)) or F == T
6. (not(T and F)) or T == T
7. (not(T and T)) or F == F
8. (not(T and T)) or T == T

Comment: Look right to me.  Think about why not (x and y) or z is true unless x and y are true and z false, and it will make sense to you.

Comment: This is correct. This should tell you a lot about how ors and ands work

Comment: Yes this is correct.

Comment: Looks fine. First, everywhere where you have `or T` the answer is `T`. For the rest, you get `T` if the expression in the inner parentheses is false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can develop everything, even if it's not really efficient (every line that is of the form `expr or T` is true):

```
(not(F and F)) or F == not(F) or F == T or F == T
(not(F and F)) or T == not(F) or T == T or T == T
(not(F and T)) or F == not(F) or F == T or F == T
(not(F and T)) or T == not(F) or T == T or T == T
(not(T and F)) or F == not(F) or F == T or F == T
(not(T and F)) or T == not(F) or T == T or T == T
(not(T and T)) or F == not(T) or F == F or F == F
(not(T and T)) or T == not(T) or T == F or T == T
```

Answer (score 0):

That is correct.

By de Morgan's Law: $\def\tnot{\operatorname{\sf not}}\def\tand{\operatorname{\sf and}}\def\tor{\operatorname{\sf or}} \tnot(a\tand b)\tor c = \tnot(a\tand b\tand\tnot c)$

Thus the sentence is false *only* for the line: $\rm\tnot(T\tand T)\tor F$.

Answer (score 0):

Reading this as statement of classical logic, you can solve this by modeling it in Boolean algebra. There are infinite models, but the simplest is this association:

---

$T\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \mapsto\ \ \ \ 1$

$\neg x\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \mapsto\ \ \ \ 1-x$

$x\land y\ \ \ \ \mapsto\ \ \ \ x\cdot y$

---

And $F$ equals $\neg T$ and $x\lor y$ equals $\neg x\land \neg y$.

Do the translations and see if true statements result.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking at all eight possible truth values in $\lnot(x \land y) \lor z$.

Using simple Boolean laws:

$$ \lnot(x \land y) \lor z = (\lnot x \lor \lnot y) \lor z$$

and the latter formula always evaluates to true, *except* when **all** its or-ed terms are false.

So $\lnot(x \land y) \lor z = 0$ iff $x=1,y=1,z=0$, which corresponds to your case $7$.